# How do you default select gcc?

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, clang, homebrew

Just to prove I have latest gcc

```
brew upgrade gcc
Error: gcc-4.8.2_1 already installed
```

I have latest gcc installed but for some reason I get this error trying to compile WebKit-gtk2

```
configure: error: Compiler GCC >= 4.7 or Clang >= 3.3 
is required for C compilation
```

My default is 4.2.1 but Clang is 5.1!

```
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

2 Questions:

1. How do I set my default gcc?
2. Why is the compile failing if Clang is > 3.3?

Comment: Try running "which gcc" to see if you are running the homebrew one.

Comment: @Mark it just says this: `/usr/bin/gcc` ...

Comment: I think your PATH is wrong then because I believe the Homebrew one is in /usr/local/bin

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH will fix it temporarily. For a permanent fix put that in ~/.profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your PATH is not set correctly to use the `gcc` provided by Homebrew. Try running:

```
which gcc
```

and, if it does not show `/usr/local/bin/gcc` your PATH is wrong.

You can temporarily fix it with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to add Homebrew's executables to the start of your PATH and, for a permanent fix, add the same command to your ~/.profile.

By the way, if you use Homebrew, you should consider running

```
brew doctor
```

every now and then to check all your settings - I am pretty sure it would have found this for you.